# create customized roles in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I want to create a customized role in MongoDB. I am following the link from Mongo docs :
http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/define-roles/

But in this link it has mentioned that one should have "createRole" and "GrantRole" action for creation of customized role.
So, I am not sure where can I find this and if its not there how to get this actions ?

Please help me if any one has created customized role in MongoDB.
Basically, I want to have this customize role so that I can have authentication over collection level.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's assuming you're already using auth, are an authorized user, and you have the roles createRole and GrantRole. If you haven't turned auth on yet and are merely configuring it, you may be ok.

Otherwise, you'll need to create a user, grant it the two roles, and then log into the mongo shell as that user to create and grant the roles.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to create a user defined role under a 2.4 release of MongoDB. The createRole and grantRole functions were not implemented until the 2.6 release. Can you please download MongoDB 2.6 and test with that?